# How do I run a cron job 45 minutes past the hour on google app engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cron

I'm working on an app for google app engine that fetches data from facebook, twitter, and email every 15, 30, and 45 minutes past the hour. I've read the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron), but I'm not seeing a way to do it. Am I missing something? Thank you for your time and attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 24 different cron jobs with the formats:

every day 00:45
every day 01:45
every day 02:45

etc.

They can all use the same handler.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be easier to just run it on a set interval like this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cronentries>
  <cron>
    <url>/fetch-data</url>
    <description>Fetch data every 15 minutes</description>
    <schedule>every 15 minutes</schedule>
  </cron>
</cronentries>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need your job to start precisely 15mn, 30mn and 45mn **past the hour**, it's possible with the combination of 3 crons calling the same url:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cronentries>
    <cron>
        <url>/cron/everyHour</url>
        <description>Every hour 1</description>
        <schedule>every 1 hours from 00:15 to 23:15</schedule>
        <timezone>Europe/Paris</timezone>
    </cron>
    <cron>
        <url>/cron/everyHour</url>
        <description>Every hour 2</description>
        <schedule>every 1 hours from 00:30 to 23:30</schedule>
        <timezone>Europe/Paris</timezone>
    </cron>
    <cron>
        <url>/cron/everyHour</url>
        <description>Every hour 3</description>
        <schedule>every 1 hours from 00:45 to 23:45</schedule>
        <timezone>Europe/Paris</timezone>
    </cron>
</cronentries>
```